# Unable to use existing tables for laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I have been trying to follow some online links for understanding how eloquent can be used in defining relationships in table.What I would actually want to try is to use my existing tables for creating models and then define relationships using eloquent.
Now I am not using migrations, since I had already created my tables and have configured the connection and other settings(mysql) in the database.php as well as .env file.

Follwing is my Article modal:

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Article extends Model
{

 protected $table = 'articles';

}
```

Since I don't make use of any migrations, I have specified my table name(articles), where I have already inserted some data.
Now just to check whether the modal works properly, I tried giving a route in web.php as follows:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {

    echo Article::all();
});
```

But now when try running the same on the server, it gives me an error saying "Class Article not found".What seems to be the issue here?

Following is my .env file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:RVOuXWd9zPWrrdIEIHoezPBrfQqHPTihq4WUgXk3xjU=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=shetty@123
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Following is the database.php file:

```
<?php

return [


    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'shetty@123'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

    ],


    'migrations' => 'migrations',


    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: You need to specify full path of your model which is usually inside App Directory.

Comment: As in inside the route??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your Article class is in a different namespace than your routes file.

At the top of your routes file include this statement:

```
use App\Article;
```

You can now reference the Article class in your route closure as Article::method();

Or alternatively, precede the call to all() as so:

```
\App\Article:all();
```

But make sure you do one or the other, not both as it is unnecessary.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I added the statement, and it now shows me the following error:could not find driver (SQL: select * from `articles`)

Comment: What's your config/database.php and .env file look like?

Comment: Please check it now.

Comment: Looks to me like the mysql php extension is not enabled. What's your dev environment? Are you using laravel valet or something like XAMPP perhaps? Running "php -m" in your console/terminal should tell you if mysql module is installed.

Comment: I tried running "php -m " and was able to view mysql in the list displayed, I use mysql workbench, and as for laravel I have been creating projects through composer and working on it.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not familiar with mysql workbench. Maybe try installing regular mysql. What does phpinfo(); output? Do you see the mysql extension enabled in there?

Comment: I do have the regular mysql as well, and am able to view my tables in it as well. phpinfo() does show mysql, which means it's installed right?

Comment: Yeah, then the extension is not the answer. Are you getting a PDO error? What's the exact error output say and what's the stack look like? Is extension=pdo_mysql.so uncommented in your php.ini file? Also, do you have doctrine/dbal composer package required for the project? If not, that might be it.

Comment: I do get a pdo error as well, And I have installed doctrine/dbal composer package now, but it still gives me pdo error as well as the previous one related to drivers.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that I haven't used any migrations right? I am just a little confused here

Comment: I don't think so, not according to the error anyway.

Comment: The error that i get now is this:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers (SQL: select * from `articles`)

I guess it has something to do with default charset used by mysql, but I dont have much understanding about the same.

Comment: What did you change that gave you this new error? Also, what charset is your database and tables configured to?

Comment: Hey, Sorry for the delay in reply, I had been trying to work on this for the entire day.I figured out that it ultimately had something to do with the version of mysql and php that I had been using, could be that they weren't compatible with each other(I was using php 7 and mysql 8.0), and while trying to figure all this out, something caused laravel to stop working all together.So I then installed wamp and tried doing the same throrugh composer, it works well now.Thanks for your help, Really appreciate it.